# How can I fix my broken system clock (battery dead)?

Tags: gnome, fedora

I have a very old laptop with a dead battery. So every time I unplug the laptop the system time is reset to 2008.

I installed both Windows 7 and Fedora 16, but every time I boot directly into Fedora after unplugging the laptop, Gnome3 failed to start.
I later found out it has something to do with the system time error.

Now what I do is first boot into Windows 7, change the system time without unplugging the power and reboot into Fedora 16.

Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: Replace the battery

Comment: i wish i had the money.

Comment: He's talking about the CMOS battery. They're less than $2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your laptop is first powered on, you'll usually get a prompt to hit F2 (or something similiar) to enter the BIOS setup. You can set the time there, faster than rebooting another OS.
Of course, replacing the CMOS system battery is the best solution and really not expensive or technically hard. You can find a new CMOS on ebay for a few bucks. Then google your laptop model and "system battery" to find instructions on replacement. If the design was friendly enough, it might be located under one of the bottom side removable covers, or by removing the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Does booting to a command line in Fedora, setting the time, and then manually starting the GUI make it any easier (or work)?

Comment: i haven't tried , but i am trying to find an easier way, cause i remember that i don't have this problem in fedora 15.